# Spring Boot not being terminated after adding Elasticsearch dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

My Spring Boot Application is just performing data ingestion task and it should be terminated after the process. Recently we've added elasticsearch and data are being pushed to elasticsearch server. However, now application not being terminated after adding these dependencies.

```
<spring-data-elasticsearch.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-data-elasticsearch.version>
<elasticsearch.version>7.4.0</elasticsearch.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How did you terminate your application after complete the task?

Comment: besides Sankar's question - SDE 4.0.0.RELEASE was built against the Elasticsearch libraries in version 7.6.2 . Providing versions 7.4.0 might lead to errors if Elasticsearch changed their API between these versions - and as fas as I remember 7.6 was one of the versions that had breaking changes.

Comment: @Sankar- it's a simple 'spring-boot-starter' application with 'CommandLineRunner'. won't create an embedded server.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch- thanks. will update version to 7.6.2. but still, issue is not resolved. not sure but somehow these dependencies make the application a never-ending project(maybe web)!